# What is the difference between relativedelta() and DateOffset()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta, python-dateutil

I am having trouble understanding the differences between the relativedelta() function from the dateutil module and the DateOffset() function from Pandas. To me their syntax and outcomes are the same. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

current_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-09-10')

print('current_date + relativedelta(months = 1)')
print('current_date + pd.DateOffset(months = 1)')
```

Results:

2023-10-10 00:00:00

2023-10-10 00:00:00

Comment: The main difference between the two is that relativedelta objects are used for calculating differences between two dates, whereas DateOffsets are used for incrementing dates by a specified amount of time.

Comment: Thanks Tejas. This comes from the first result of the google search, but I don't know what this means. The example provided in the article did not address the differences either

Comment: *"Works exactly like the keyword argument form of relativedelta."* - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset — As for _why_ pandas felt the need to add this, your guess is as good as mine. Perhaps to have the entire API all "in house" and not requiring you to `import` weird 3rd party modules you've never heard of. Probably also to have control over the API; i.e. should `dateutil` decide to drastically alter its API in the future, pandas could just implement everything in `DateOffset` without breaking.

Answer (score 0):

both functions do the same thing. The pandas function can be used for vectorized operations like :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-31'), columns=['date'])
```

And you can add the offset to all values :

```
df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

DateOffset takes care of daylight saving, Timedelta does not.

```py
import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd
import pytz
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


t = pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam").localize(dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1))
print(f"start: {t}")
print(f"{t + pd.DateOffset(months=3)} using offset")
print(f"{t + relativedelta(months=3)} using relativedelta")
```

gives

```
start: 2000-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
2000-04-01 00:00:00+02:00 using offset
2000-04-01 00:00:00+01:00 using relativedelta
```